# How to use Auth class from Laravel Framework in normal PHP file

Tags: php, laravel

I have an integration.php file which is in public/arrowchat/includes/integration.php

I was wondering how do I access the Auth class within there.

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php
    use Auth;

    function get_user_id() 
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) 
        {
            return NULL;
        } else {
            return Auth::user()->id;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm using laravel framework

Comment: What you should do is to specify why "it doesn't seem to work". Is it throwing an error? What error? Without it, we'll just be guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Auth facade in a plain (read - invoked/executed directly, not within the the framework) PHP file, you still need to require composer autoloader so that classes such as `Auth` are loaded. In your example above, you are most likely to get an unknown class error.

But even then, `Auth` most probably relies on classes like `Request` to get the headers and cookies and `Request` is initialised in Laravel bootstrap.

If you really, really need to do this - you will have to copy/paste some of the bootstrap stuff from Laravel's bootstrapper in order to make this work.

Otherwise, I would recommend you to make a Laravel console command instead and then everything will just work out of the box.